# How should one authenticate his gmail account over a web server?

Tags: php, zend-framework, gmail, password-protection

I use Zend to send emails from my web application. However the password is plain text. I want to use some other method or password in order keep my email password from hidden eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail supports [OAuth over IMAP/SMTP](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/) as an alternative method to password authentication.  See [PHP - Getting Started](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/wiki/PhpSampleCode) for documentation and examples in PHP.  It uses the Zend Framework for OAuth and IMAP/SMTP.

Alternatively, you could store your password somewhere in encrypted form, and decrypt it each time you go to use it.  That way, it isn't stored in the database or file in plain text.